# Chromedriver not clicking on object coordinates while in W10 VM

Tags: selenium, click, windows-10, virtual-machine

I have a veeeeery weird issue I can not get solved, I am using Selenium together with Java, all bindings are up to date and Chrome browsers is up to date.

My main testing is done in Windows machines using mobile emulation.

When I launch my test cases in a Windows 7 real machine / Windows 7 Virtual Machine or Windows 10 real machine they are working ok, but when I launch them in any Windows 10 Virtual Machine selenium starts clicking on wrong coordinates.

IE. I have a button placed in (70, 612), selenium is able to get the element coordinates without issues but when using click() it is actually clicking somewhere else (it is opening a banner or an event).

If I use javascript click it is working with no issues, it is just selenium click() command and only in W10 VM (I have tried a Windows Server 2016 VM as well).

I have tried to low and raise mobile pixel density and always having same results.

As an extra, this issue is not reproducible when testing on chrome desktop (no emulation) so I think it should be related with how Selenium is calculating where to click.

I hope someone had the same issue and be able to show some light to this.

Best regards.

Some Code trials as requested:

I am parsing device metrics (Height,Width,PixelRatio)

```
Map<String, Object> deviceMetrics = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    deviceMetrics.put("width", this.width);
    deviceMetrics.put("height", this.height);
    deviceMetrics.put("pixelRatio", this.pixelRatio);

    Map<String, Object> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    mobileEmulation.put("deviceMetrics", deviceMetrics);
    mobileEmulation.put("userAgent", this.userAgent);

    LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
    logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);

    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
    chromeOptions.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);
    chromeOptions.setCapability(CapabilityType.ROTATABLE, true);
    chromeOptions.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR,
            org.openqa.selenium.UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.ACCEPT);
    if(scope.equals("performance"))if(scope.equals("performance"))
        chromeOptions.setProxy(seleniumProxy);
    chromeOptions.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
```

Then init remoteWD.

```
try {
        return new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://xxxxxx.xxxx.com:4444/wd/hub"), chromeOptions);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Driver creation failed");
        return new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);

    }
```

Device Metrics Example:

```
switch (driverName) {
        case "Samsung S7":
            setDeviceData(GALAXY_S7_USER_AGENT, orientation, 360, 640, 2.8, driverName);
            deviceKind="mobile";
            break;
        case "Samsung S6":
            setDeviceData(GALAXY_S6_USER_AGENT, orientation, 360, 640, 2.8, driverName);
            deviceKind="mobile";
            break;
        case "Samsung S5":
            setDeviceData(GALAXY_S5_USER_AGENT, orientation, 360, 640, 2.8, driverName);
            deviceKind="mobile";
            break;
```

And this is an example of a simple test case

```
@Test(retryAnalyzer = RetryAnalyzerImpl.class)
public void LogInLogOut() throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
    ATUReports.setAuthorInfo("Daniel Prado Pino", Utils.getCurrentTime(),"1.0");

    driver.get("https://www.elotrolado.net");
    sleep(3000);
    log.info("Click");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#h-mobile-nav-btn")).click();
    log.info("Clicked");
    sleep(10000);
}
```

note: For this test case I hace Selenium StandAlone 3.1.3 running together with Chromedriver 2.40 in a Windows Server 2016 Virtual Machine. I have reproduced it as well in Windows 10 Virtual Machine executed through jenkins / maven.

Comment: Some code trials please

Comment: This issue is something related on how W10 VM is rendering, I have tried "headless" chrome and everything is working fine...